# Trigger same JQuery for multiple controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a `JQuery` function. I want to trigger it for `checkbox` and `radio` button click event. Based on which control trigger the `JQuery` function, respective `__doPostBack('<%=control.UniqueID%>', "")` statement should be run

**JQuery`**

```
<script>
    function DiscountAtLast(chk) {
        $(function () {

            var discount_end = document.createElement("INPUT");
            discount_end.type = "hidden";
            discount_end.name = "discount_end";

            if (chk.checked) {
                var pos = { my: "center center", at: "center top+150", of: window };

                $("#popupdiv").dialog({
                    title: "Login Info",
                    resizable: false,
                    height: "auto",
                    width: 400,
                    buttons: {
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            
                            return false;

                        },
                        Ok: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                            discount_end.value = $("[id*='pass']").val();
                            document.forms[0].appendChild(discount_end);

                            if (chk == DiscountAtEnd)
                                __doPostBack('<%=btnDiscountAtEnd.UniqueID%>', "");

                            if (chk == r4)
                                __doPostBack('<%=btnRadior4.UniqueID%>', "");

                            $("[id*=popupdiv]").empty();

                            return true;
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

**asp.net**

Following checkbox click event trigger JQuery `DiscountAtLast(chk)`

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="DiscountAtEnd" Text="Offer Discount" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnClick="return DiscountAtLast(this);" ViewStateMode="Enabled"/>    
<asp:Button ID="btnDiscountAtEnd" runat="server" style="display:none;" Text="Button" OnClick="btnDiscountAtEnd_Click" />
```

Following radio button click event **Also trigger same** JQuery DiscountAtLast(chk)

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="r4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  OnClick="return DiscountAtLast(this);" />
<asp:Button ID="btnRadior4" runat="server"  Text="Button" OnClick="btnRadior4_Click" />
```

**Require Behavior**

How to use if else statement in `JQuery` that will decide that which control has trigger it so that either  `__doPostBack('<%=btnDiscountAtEnd.UniqueID%>', "")` or `__doPostBack('<%=btnRadior4.UniqueID%>', "")` should execute.

Comment: ist not clear, i dont understand why you want to implement a sort of if/else  with checkbox or radio?

Comment: JQuery popup is basically login for. Same login form is required for either control. Based on which control has trigger it respective C# at server function will run

Comment: you have *2 if in the OK section*, its not what you want ->  execute the right function following the radio or checkbox clicked?

Comment: Sorry, yes i want to execute respective __doPostBack statement using if else

Comment: `chk.id` in your js/jquery code will give you ID of the control that was clicked